# Index a DB table directly into Solr

Tags: solr

I want to import data from database directly into the solr index. I found [this tutorial very helpful](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart).

However I have a problem to get this to work. I first set up a requestHandler like this

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" 
                class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/admin_pproject" 
              user="root" 
              password=""/>
  <document>
    <entity name="id" 
            query="select id from admin_pproject">
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

When I run full import I get several errors:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the full path to `data-config.xml` in solrconfig. Also, check what happens if you try to access http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/dataimport.jsp?handler=/dataimport from a browser.

If you still have problems, then please post the Jetty logs generated while starting Solr - they might provide clues.

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right files and restarting Jetty after changing the config files? Please shut down Jetty, clear the logs, start Jetty, fire the full-import command and post the full log file. Upload it on some server and provide a link if it is too big.

Comment: Well I did exactly what is described here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart and I restarted the server, this is the new log http://pastebin.com/nhfUVqwr

Comment: Well, I was expecting the log to show much more (I use Tomcat and a whole lot gets logged as soon as I start Solr/Tomcat, don't have any experience with Jetty, it might be different, or it might depend on the logging levels.)  Just verify that you are editing the right config files - go to http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/file/?file=solrconfig.xml and check that the dataimport config is present.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I noticed that I have several solrconfig files, and actually it seems to be that I edited the wrong in example/solr/conf/...which should be edited?

Comment: Open localhost:8983/solr/admin/index.jsp and you will see `SolrHome=<directory>` towards the top.  That is your home directory for Solr. The correct solrconfig to edit would be in the conf directory inside SolrHome.

Comment: thank you so far, however there are still errors, I edited my question.

Comment: This is a totally different issue, and I think you should ask a separate question. The idea behind StackOverflow is to create a repository of answers which can be used by others who have the same problems. The current question is so different from the original that another user who has the same issue will never find this page. Anyway, the Exception clearly says that admin_pproject.admin_pproject does not exist - please check that there is a database called admin_pproject with a table called admin_pproject. Is the double p a typo or did you really mean to write pproject?

Comment: thanks for the hint, in entity it must be the table name where I had the db name