# error importing MYSQL table rows into solr using DataImportHandler

Tags: mysql, solr

I want to index  MySQL table with **Solr4.0** row by row . I have installed the necessary java my database is called 'twitter_db' and the table i want ot index called "tweets"
and i login using user : root and no password

the schema is so i added it in the :

```
   <dataConfig>
        <dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/twitter_db" user="root" password="" />
    <document name="tweet">
            <entity name="tweet" query="select * from tweets">
                <field column="tweet_id" name="tweet_id" />
                <field column="text" name="text" />            
                <field column="user" name="user" />
                <field column="tweet_time" name="tweet_time" />
                <field column="topic_kw" name="topic_kw" />
                <field column="timestamp" name="timestamp" />
            </entity>
        </document>
    </dataConfig>
```

and the solrconfig changes is:

```
 <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

and when i hit [root]:8983/solr/db/dataimport?command=full-import
  for full import

it fails : error message in the GUI is :

> Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.

and the the part of the error message in the log is :

```
SEVERE: Exception while processing: tweet document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select * from tweets Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:252)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:209)
```

i wonder if it's a wrong data in selecting the database of the table

i tried a [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284586/index-a-db-table-directly-into-solr) it's a similar problem but i didn't find the answer there

Comment: Whats the full stack trace ? are there more exceptions ? you can try running DIH in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check `driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"` it is **hsqldb** rather it should be pointing to MySQL driver class. Try updating the driver class to appropriate driver for MySQL & you can run it in debug mode.